# How to get related model field with namespaced models in Laravel 4?

Tags: model, laravel, namespaces, laravel-4, relationship

Ok I have those models

*app/models/article.php*

```
<?php 
namespace Models;

class Article extends \Eloquent {

    protected $table = 'articles';

    public function author() {
        return $this->belongsTo('Models\Author');
    }
}
```

*app/models/author.php*

```
<?php 
namespace Models;

class Author extends \Eloquent {

    protected $table = 'authors';

    public function article() {
        return $this->hasMany('Models\Article');
    }
}
```

Now let's make a test with a controller

*app/controllers/admin/TestController.php*

```
<?php
namespace Admin;

use Models\Article;

class TestController extends BaseController {

    public function test()
    {
        $article = Article::first();
        sd($article->author->id);
    }
}
```

Now when I route to `Admin\\TestController@test` I get this exception

**Trying to get property of non-object** on `sd($article->author->id);`

Why? What I did wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you did not got errors before that, it's almost all working so:

```
$article = Article::first();
```

Is in fact and the same as

```
$article = \Models\Article::first();
```

But if `$article` or `->author` are not objects is because your `articles` table is empty or there is no relation set (in database) between `authors` and `articles`.

Comment: well it's not $article the problem. In fact if i dump $article I get the object. But if I dump $article->author I get NULL! So the problem is the relationship O_O

Comment: You saved me! I checked and I had non existant author IDs in the author_id field of the articles table.
It was due to a strange behavior in the seeding operation.
Thank you!